# How to change the width of dialog in android compose

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

It seems impossible to change the width of the dialog with Compose.
The closest I've come to with changing the dialog width is through `DialogProperties.usePlatformDefaultWidth`. Setting it to false causes the dialog to fill the screen but is there a way to use custom width?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use can define a custom [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)) using the constructor with `text`,`title` and `buttons` parameters and applying a **size** (for example with the `Modifier.size`) and overriding the default behaviour with `usePlatformDefaultWidth = false` :

```
AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
    title = {
        Text(text = "Title")
    },
    text = {
        Text(
            "This area typically contains the supportive text " +
                    "which presents the details regarding the Dialog's purpose."
        )
    },
    buttons = {},
    properties = DialogProperties(
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp,250.dp)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is can only be used to set a size smaller than the platform default width and *not a size bigger than it*

Comment: I tried setting usePlatformDefaultWidth to false and that works. I can increase or decrease the size as compared to the default

Comment: I think for the modifier to work you need to override the default value of `usePlatformDefaultWidth` (which is `true`) and set it to `false`. Then you can increase (or decrease) the size with the `modifier`.

Comment: @Kofi You are right about increasing the size Updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a constant width in all your project you can create a dialog with customized width as follows

```
@Composable
fun MyCustomDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        // We are copying the passed properties 
        // then setting usePlatformDefaultWidth to false
        properties = properties.let {
            DialogProperties(
                dismissOnBackPress = it.dismissOnBackPress,
                dismissOnClickOutside = it.dismissOnClickOutside,
                securePolicy = it.securePolicy,
                usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
            )
        },
        content = {
            Surface(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                modifier = Modifier.width(250.dp), // Customize your width here
                content = content
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialog(
properties = DialogProperties(
usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
),
){
Box()....
}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "DialogState" to set the size of Dialog:

```
var isDialogOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val dialogState = rememberDialogState(position = WindowPosition(x = 500.dp, y = 500.dp), size = DpSize(100.dp, 100.dp))
if (isDialogOpen){
    Dialog(title = "This is Dialog",
        state = dialogState,
        transparent = false,
        undecorated = false,
        resizable = false,
        onCloseRequest = {}) {
        Button(onClick = {
            isDialogOpen = false
        }) {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}
```